# Operations on Specific Columns on a Tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I've started using TensorFlow recently and am confused on how to approach column specific operations. The tensor I am dealing with is shaped [? , 12] and I want to multiply columns: 1 , 4 , 7, and 10 by 200 and for one column I want to round each value in it to nearest integer. I've looked at the docs but have found no concrete way to accomplish this task. Speaking generically how can I execute these operations in TensorFlow? Is there no operator to retrieve specific columns and/or do operations on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)